# Boost and system cache

Tags: caching

I'm using the Drupal-7 system caching and i recently installed the Boost module to improve my site performence;
I'm wondering if there's no conflict between the two system caching because i didn't feel any increasing of my site rapidity .
Thank you very much

Comment: The core cache and the boost cache do not interfere with each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Boost for my [company website](http://webdrips.com), and have been pleased with the results.

Did you disable "Cache pages for anonymous users" in the performance settings? Did you add the extra settings required by boost in your .htaccess file? Are you only viewing the site as an anonymous user? Have you made sure the /[drupal-base]/cache is readable by Apache, and /[drupal-base]/cache/normal is readable and writable by Apache?

If yes to all the above, you likely have other issues slowing down your site, such as too little overall RAM (or too much RAM allocated in the allowed_memory setting).

Comment: Thank you very much your ansewer is very helpful,but i have another question: if i edit a page within the cache lifecycle, which version of the page the anonymous user will see?

Comment: All the above configurations are applied;and my  /[drupal-base]/cache/normal and  /[drupal-base]/cache/ have 705 permission, is that correct?

Comment: Editing a page should clear the cache for that page in most circumstances. I have my permissions set to 750 for cache, and 770 for normal. You can check the site status report to see if boost complains of incorrect permissions.

Comment: RAM allocations do not speed up or slow down Drupal. If there is too little ram, the process will die with a WSOD saying "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of XXX bytes exhausted ...". Giving PHP lots of ram (1024M+) won't speed Drupal up. The script either has enough ram to run or it doesn't.

Comment: @mikeytown, that's not true: https://library.acquia.com/articles/conditionally-increasing-memory-limits

Comment: Clarification: your first sentence is not true; the rest of the paragraph is correct. I still stand by my last paragraph above 100%.

Comment: From a global perspective (looking at concurrent connections to Apache) Webdrips is correct :) From a per process perspective more or less ram doesn't affect PHP's speed.

Comment: Please tell me if i'm wrong:For my boost configuration i am using for Servers URL or Name: %{HTTP_HOST}
for Document Root: %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}
In another way, i'm confused by what do you mean by the root of the web server :i'm hosting my website in a host company and i dropped my drupal files in the 'www' folder ,that mean that my index.php is at www/index.php .
So should i modify the 'www/.htaccess ' file or the .htaccess situated at the same level as the www folder .

Answer (score 1):

The Drupal 7 version of Boost will not function properly while Drupal core cache is enabled. Go to the Performance page (/admin/config/development/performance) and make sure that "Cache pages for anonymous users" is NOT checked.

For a full recipe how to configure and test Boost for D7, along with conditional expiration and a crawler, see [this article](http://vacilando.org/article/drupal-performance-mantra-crawl-boost-expire).

Comment: Be sure drupal core cache is not checked,and boost will not work if it's enabled